# why I'm getting NullPointerException

Tags: java

this is my code and when I run this example it gives `NullPointerException`
could you help me please to find the error or why I've got this exception !
my code :

```
public class Frame extends JFrame
{
    public Frame()
    {
        JLabel label;
        label.setText("test");
        add(label);
        setSize(200,200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Frame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide stack trace?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: JLabel label = new JLabel(); label.setText("test");

Answer (score 1):

You declare a `JLabel` variable :

```
    JLabel label;
```

And you access it without initializing it first :

```
    label.setText("test");
```

You must initialize a variable before accessing it :

```
    JLabel label = new JLabel ();
    label.setText("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized label;